# Get centroid from map with changing boundaries

Tags: r, gis, r-sp, centroid

I'm working with a package called histmaps (found here 
https://github.com/junkka/histmaps ) where information about historical boundaries of administrative zones in Sweden is stored. I'm interested in finding the centroid of each parish that existed between the years 1900 and 1920. Since the boundaries of the parishes were changing over time, some adjustments need to made.

The creator of the package has solved this by introducing hist_boundaries, like:

period_map <- hist_boundaries(c(1900, 1920))

Now, I'm completely clueless on how to find the centroids of each parish from the period map.

I've tried this code:

```
centroids <- 
  gCentroid(
    spgeom = methods::as( object = period_map, Class = 'Spatial' )
    , byid = TRUE
  )
```

but that only returns:

```
Error in methods::as(object = period_map, Class = "Spatial") : 
  no method or default for coercing “list” to “Spatial”
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you download the parish boundaries in `{sf}` package format (there seems to be format parameter just for this purpose); you will be then able to apply the function `sf::st_centroid()`.

```
library(histmaps)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

polygons <- hist_boundaries(1900, format = "sf")

centroids <- polygons %>% 
  st_centroid()

plot(st_geometry(polygons))
plot(centroids, pch = 4, col = "red", add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: @johnny I have updated my answer to show how :) the key part is format = "sf" argument in your hist_boundaries() call

Comment: Sorry to bother you, @Jindra, but just one more thing. Were you able to make it work the same way when polygons <- hist_boundaries(c(1900, 1920), format = "sf"), that is when dealing with a period longer than a year?

Comment: nope, but that is not an issue with centroids but with the hist_boundaries function - the result it returns for multiple periods does not seem quite legit. Consider object.size(hist_boundaries(c(1900, 1920), format = "sf")) - you would expect it to be roughly equal to sum of object.size(hist_boundaries(c(1900), format = "sf")) and object.size(hist_boundaries(c(1920), format = "sf")). It clearly is not.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Have a great weekend, and thank you for your patience!